# jQuery code to change & fade background-image CSS ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a jQuery background fader from background to background.

I have a base to go off, but have had no success.

I have all the proper libraries included, I have triple checked.

```js
//Array of images which you want to show: Use path you want.
  var images = new Array('img/bg_0.jpg', 'img/bg_1.jpg', 'img/bg_2.jpg');
  var nextimage = 0;
  doSlideshow();

  function doSlideshow() {
    if (nextimage >= images.length) {
      nextimage = 0;
    }
    $('.face')
      .css('background-image', 'url("' + images[nextimage++] + '")')
      .fadeIn(500, function() {
        setTimeout(doSlideshow, 1000);
      });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="face" style="background-image: url('img/bg_5.jpg');" class="face">
  <div class="face-body">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1 class="face-title one">
        <?php echo SRV_NAME; ?>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="face-subtitle">
        <?php echo SRV_SLOGAN; ?>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't fade just the background of an element. in your code, `.fadeIn()` has an effect on the whole `.face` element... Including the child elements (the inner divs, h1 and h2). Just use a regular `<img>` element and look for `position:absolute` and `z-index`.

Comment: sooo what are you suggesting i do?  I don't have much experinece on jQuery itself, especially in this situation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `<img>` element if you wish to fade in/out.
A background can't be animated. Only elements can. A background isn't an element, it is a property of an element.

So what I suggest here is to get rid of the background idea and use an absolute positionned image element (to have it behind your text, as a background does).

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
//Array of images which you want to show: Use path you want.
var images = new Array('http://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/hypoallergenic-cat-breeds.jpg', 'https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/640/clsd/getty/c64f76dc20c246ca88ee180fe4b4b781', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg');
var nextimage = 0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow() {
  if (nextimage >= images.length) {
    nextimage = 0;
  }
  $('.face')
    .fadeOut(500,function(){
    $(this).attr('src', images[nextimage++])
      .fadeIn(500, function() {
      setTimeout(doSlideshow, 1000);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.face{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="face">
  <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/what-does-it-mean-when-cat-wags-tail.jpg" class="face">
  <div class="face-body">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1 class="face-title one">
        NAME
      </h1>
      <h2 class="face-subtitle">
        SLOGAN
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```